# Как получить int 000023 (лидирующие нули)?

Tags: java

У меня есть задание: нужно сделать метод, который будет принимать значение и возвращать `int`.

Так вот, возвращаемый `int` должен быть 6-значным числом, и суть в том, что если число, которое обработал метод в итоге размером всего, допустим, в 2 знака, то спереди должно добавиться четыре нуля.

Допустим, метод в результате дал число `23`, то вернуть он должен `000023`.

Но `int` сбрасывает ненужные нули и в итоге все равно `23`.

Есть возможность получить такое число, используя `int`?

Comment: Нет, [потому что это число](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988). Используй строку.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну это я понимаю, что со строкой можно такое сделать, интересно было может как то можно сделать через число

Comment: Перечитай по ссылке.

Comment: Добавил примерчик в своем ответе

Comment: 23 или 0000023 - это представление числа в понятном для человека виде. Внутреннее представление - это набор байт. Сам тип `int` как тип никак нули не отбрасывает, поэтому вам нужно просто выбрать нужное форматирование при выводе, например как показано в ответе @PavelBereznichenko.

Answer (score 5):

Если нужно распечатать то вот так

```
System.out.format("%04d\n", 1);
System.out.format("%07\n", 23);
System.out.format("%04d\n", 84);
System.out.format("%04d\n", 100);
```

output:

```
0001
0000023
0084
0100
```

Comment: Та это я знаю, что можно форматировать, интересно есть ли возможность как то с числом такое сделать

Comment: @Aleksey Timoshchenko насколько я знаю и на сколько "гуглил", в java нет такой возможности, может быть в каком то другом языке

Answer (score 5):

Нет, [потому что это число](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/178988). Используй строку.

> что я должен был увидеть?

Что у чисел не бывает лидирующих нулей. На них всегда в памяти выделено определённое число бит. И среди этих бит нет никакой информации про текстовое представление.

Comment: И все же (с *некоторыми* (мягко говоря) ограничениями) такой трюк возможен.

Comment: @avp, ну так-то и битовые поля заюзать можно. Но по сути это уже структура, а не число.

Comment: А где в Java битовые поля? Моделировать, конечно же, можно.

Comment: @avp, не знаю, кажется, нет :)

Answer (score 2):

Все-таки можно, если ограничить диапазон хранимых чисел. Например, число можно умножить на 10 и сложить с числом лидирующих нулей. По сути дела, используем целую переменную в качестве контейнера как для битов значения числа, так  и дополнительной информации (в данном случае количества лидирующих нулей).

Максимальное (и минимальное, т.е. отрицательное) значение, которое можно записать в такую переменную, сокращается в 10 раз.

Только при остальной работе с ним, для получения исходного числа надо не забывать делить на 10, а для получения лидирующих нулей берем остаток от деления на 10.

Небольшой пример (но на Си, поскольку Java под рукой нет)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int zint (int x)
{
  int z = x, n = 1;

  while (z /= 10)
    n++;
  n = (n > 5 ? 0 : 6 - n);
  return (x *= 10) >= 0 ? x + n : x - n;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int x;

  while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
    int z = zint(x);
    int nz = z < 0 ? -z % 10 : z % 10;

    printf("z = %d  nz: %d num: %d\n", z, nz, z / 10);
    printf("res: %06d\n", z / 10);
  }
}
```

**update**

На всякий случай, вот функция, которая печатает число с заданным количеством ведущих нулей (тоже Си, как и printf возвращает количество выведенных символов)

```
int zint_print (int x)
{
  int l = 0;
  if (x < 0) {
    l++;
    x = -x;
    putchar('-');
  }
  int n = x % 10;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    putchar('0');
    l++;
  }

  int r = printf("%d", x / 10);
  return r > 0 ? l + r : r;
}
```

**update 2**

А вот так

```
printf("%s%0*d%d\n", z < 0 ? "-" : "", abs(z) % 10, 0, abs(z/10));
```

можно правильно печатать такие (с упакованным в число количеством ведущих нулей) числа.

Comment: Можете какой нибудь короткий пример дать? А то я не совсем понял

Comment: На Си подойдет?

Comment: я не уверен, что это будет работать на java, но сейчас попробую переписать

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, ну как, на Java получилось?

Comment: в первой функции `zint` в цикле while уловие `z /= 10` я не знаю как как в Си , но в java условие должно возвращать boolean(я не понял что этот цикл должен делать) - это первое. А второе я не понял, что это за вторая функция? от куда взять параметры которые там указаны? И еще одно на что обратил внимание `printf("res: %06d\n", z / 10);` вы же в итоге все равно форматируете чтоб получить нужный результат... Я не думаю что тут printf("z = %d  nz: %d num: %d\n", z, nz, z / 10); z = 000023

Comment: В Си любой результат выражения, отличный от 0 это true. Т.е. цикл делит `z` на 10, пока `z` не станет 0. Видимо в Java его можно переписать так -- ` while (z / 10 != 0) {
    n++;
    z = z / 10;
  }` Вторая функция это `scanf()`? Это ввод данных. Читает целое число из stdin. В java что-то вроде `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); ... while(sc.hasNextInt()) { x = sc.nextInt(); ...` А с печатью, Вы правы, просто я не стал писать функцию, которая выводит число с лидирующими пробелами. Если нужно, то легко дополню

Comment: Эм.. `printf("%0*d", x%10, x/10)` - не?

Comment: Не, `*` это размер всего *поля* вместе с цифрами числа, а не повторитель заполняющего 0-я. Т.е. все равно надо пересчитывать (и исходя из примера в вопросе получится 6)

Comment: @Qwertiy, адресовал вам комментарий и забыл что-то, что без собаки-ник не доставится...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, я там пообновлял в комментариях и ответе, но что-то забыл вставить ваш ник, так что сейчас эти комментом оповещаю. Или вам все комментарии доставляются?

Comment: @avp, я думал, нужна фиксированная длина числа, а не фиксированное число нулей. Ладно, тогда так: `printf("%0*d%d", x%10, 0, x/10)` - годится?

Comment: @Qwertiy, хитро! Но, только для положительных. Для всех, тогда уж, вот так: `printf("%s%0*d%d\n", z < 0 ? "-" : "", abs(z) % 10, 0, abs(z/10));` (добью, пожалуй, как update в ответе)

Comment: `printf("-%0*d%d" + (z>=0), abs(z)%10, 0, abs(z)/10)` :D

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51870/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-avp).

Answer (score 0):

также можно этим способом

```
int i = 23;

String str = "000000" + i;
String substring = str.substring(str.length() - 6); // берем последние 6 знаков
System.out.println(substring);
```

результат `000023`

такой способ позволяет работать с разными типами данных и регулировать длину этих нулей

P.s.  `int` может иметь больше 6 знаков